# How to retrive values from ArrayList and put them in diffrent TextViews in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, textview

I have the following ArrayList: `ArrayList<Integer> counters;`, with 3 values in it.

I made an Intent to move this ArrayList from `Main.class`, to a new class, callesd: `two.class`.
And I want to get each value from the ArrayList, and put them in three TextViews, `tv1, tv2, tv3`, 
like this: `tv1 = value1, tv2 = value2, tv3 = value3`.
Here is my code:

**Main.class:**

```
public void moveToAns(View view) {

counters.add(countCorrect);
counters.add(countWrong);
counters.add(countTotal);

seeAns = new Intent(this, two.class);

seeAns.putExtra("seeAnswers", counters);

startActivity(seeAns);
```

}

**two.class:**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);

        intentSee = getIntent();

        seeAnsC = intentSee.getIntegerArrayListExtra("seeAnswers");

    }
```

so, what I need to do to get each value from the ArrayList into three different TextViews?

Comment: You really should post all (!) relevant code when you ask a question. The logcat info you posted on pastebin (which you should have posted here on SO with your question) indicates that the error initiated from your `onClick` method -- which you did not post!! and that you have an java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference error.

Comment: The NullPointerException means you probably did not initialize your "counters"  `ArrayList`

Comment: I fount my mistake. I tried to get unknow ArrayList because the name were not matching. I had put(countCorrect> but the get was get(seeAnswers)

Answer (score 1):

In your Main.class do this

```
public void moveToAns(View view) {
ArrayList<Integer> counters = new ArrayList();// you can declare it globally
counters.add(countCorrect);
counters.add(countWrong);
counters.add(countTotal);

seeAns = new Intent(this, two.class);

seeAns.putIntegerArrayListExtra("seeAnswers", counters);

startActivity(seeAns);
```

And in Two.class

```
 ArrayList<Integer> counters = getIntent().getIntegerArrayListExtra("seeAnswers");
 tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
 tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
 tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);

 tv1.setText("Correct answers: " + seeAnsC.get(0));
 tv2.setText("Wrong answers: " + seeAnsC.get(1));
 tv3.setText("Total answers: " + seeAnsC.get(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this should be what you're looking for. Let me know if it works :D

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);

    intentSee = getIntent();

    seeAnsC = intentSee.getIntegerArrayListExtra("seeAnswers");

    tv1.setText("Correct answers: " + seeAnsC.get(0));
    tv2.setText("Wrong answers: " + seeAnsC.get(1));
    tv3.setText("Total answers: " + seeAnsC.get(2));
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it's crashing

Comment: Edit your answer with the error you're getting on the logcat. If I can't see the error, I don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

you should use:

`seeAns.putIntegerArrayListExtra("seeAnswers", counters);`

instead of:

`seeAns.putExtra("seeAnswers", counters);`

Update:

Move the  TextView code to onStart():

```
private ArrayList<Integer> seeAnsC;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two)

    intentSee = getIntent();
    seeAnsC = intentSee.getIntegerArrayListExtra("seeAnswers");

}

protected void onStart() {
   tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
   tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
   tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);

   tv1.setText("Correct answers: " + seeAnsC.get(0));
   tv2.setText("Wrong answers: " + seeAnsC.get(1));
   tv3.setText("Total answers: " + seeAnsC.get(2));
}
```

Comment: Still crahsing.

Comment: Is "two.class" a fragment? If, so you the view hasn't been created in onCreate(). You have to update the TextViews in " onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)"

Comment: Also, in an Activity the views are visible in onStart().

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code, so we can help you. According to what your posted on pastebin, you have an error in your OnClick and a NullPointerException :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.example.user.thordrandom.Main.moveToAns(Main.java:108)
```

The NullPointerException is probably because the list is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

- initialize `ArrayList<Integer> counters;` and `ArrayList<Integer> seeAnsC;`
- change method to `seeAns.putIntegerArrayListExtra("seeAnswers", counters);`

**Main.class**

```
ArrayList<Integer> counters;

public void moveToAns(View view) {
    // Initialization
    counters = new ArrayList<>();

    counters.add(countCorrect);
    counters.add(countWrong);
    counters.add(countTotal);

    seeAns = new Intent(this, two.class);

    // change method to putIntegerArrayListExtra
    seeAns.putIntegerArrayListExtra("seeAnswers", counters);
    startActivity(seeAns);
}
```

**Two.class**

```
ArrayList<Integer> seeAnsC;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);

    intentSee = getIntent();
    // init
    seeAnsC = new ArrayList<>();
    seeAnsC = intentSee.getIntegerArrayListExtra("seeAnswers");
}
```